# ElasticSearch should for union

Tags: kotlin, elasticsearch

Consider an elasticsearch entity:

```json
PetOwner {
    dogIds: […],
    catIds: […],
    rabbitIds: […],
}
```

I am trying to implement a union clause which could search for pet owners of any of the given dogs, cats or rabbits:

```kotlin
if (dogIds != null || catIds != null || rabbitIds != null) {
    filter(
        BoolQueryBuilder().apply {
            // minimumShouldMatch(1)
            if (dogIds != null) {
                should(TermsQueryBuilder("dogIds", dogIds))
            }
            if (catIds != null) {
                should(TermsQueryBuilder("catIds", catIds))
            }
            if (rabbitIds != null) {
                should(TermsQueryBuilder("rabbitIds", rabbitIds))
            }
        }
    )
}
```

I hoped this would work as expected but it behaves in a different way - If I give dogIds and catIds, it will only search by dogIds, no pet owner of catIds will be found. Once I remove the dogIds, the owners of catIds are found.

I must be misunderstanding these queries, but I am not sure how. I also tried to fiddle with the `minimumShouldMatch`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: did  you use sql translate api ...

Comment: Can you dump the raw JSON query just before it gets sent to ES? Not sure if your kotlin client lib can do that but it'd make debugging much easier. Are you using `es-kotlin-client`?